# match common rows from ranked dataframes

Tags: r, ranking, matching

Could anyone help me to match three or more different ranked df to have a final one containing only the rows common to all of them? I am trying match and merge functions but I can not go any further.

here is how the data may look like:

```
A <- data.frame(letter=LETTERS[sample(10)], x=runif(10))
B <- data.frame(letter=LETTERS[sample(10)], x=runif(10))
C <- data.frame(letter=LETTERS[sample(10)], x=runif(10))
```

"letter" is however the "row.names" on each df has only one column with the numerical "x", the ranked values.

Comment: Every row has a match, right?

Comment: Could you please add an example of expected output?

Comment: Are you trying to merge on ranks? As in letter with same ranks in all three data frames?

Comment: Trying using 'inner_join' from dplyr package to retain rows that are common between multiple data frame columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create data

```
A <- data.frame(letter=LETTERS[sample(10)], x.A=runif(10))
B <- data.frame(letter=LETTERS[sample(10)], x.B=runif(10))
C <- data.frame(letter=LETTERS[sample(10)], x.C=runif(10))
```

Find intersecting letters in all the data.frames

```
vec.intersect <- Reduce(function(x, y) intersect(x, y), list(A[,1], B[,1], C[,1]), accumulate = FALSE)
```

Merge intersecting data.frames

```
df.intersected <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = "letter"), list(A[with(A, letter %in% vec.intersect),], B, C), accumulate = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys, and you @Pascal for the link which gave the solution by the function:

```
MyMerge       <- function(x, y){
df            <- merge(x, y, by= "row.names", all.x= F, all.y= F)
rownames(df)  <- df$Row.names
df$Row.names  <- NULL
return(df)
}
dat           <- Reduce(MyMerge, list(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6))
```

Would be possible however to re-rank the final "dat", for instance by the sum of the values of the new rows?
I am tryng stg. like that to add a column with the sum values:

```
 dat[,7] <- sum (dat[1:nrow (dat), ,drop=F])
```

but I get the sum of all values of "dat", not for each row.

Comment: Thank you for your help!